# PHP Slim REST API returns null after calling get function

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have developed a simple REST API using PHP Slim and implemented a simple function which will return a list of track upon matching the album name passed thought REST call.

This is my index.php file for making those rest calls,

**http://localhost/my_gallery/v1/tracks/:name**

```
$app->get('/tracks/:name', 'authenticate', function($album_keyword) {
    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    $db = new DbHandler();

    // fetch task
    $result = $db->getTracksByName($album_keyword);

    if ($result != NULL) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["album_name"] = $result["album_name"];
        $response["track_artist"] = $result["track_artist"];
        $response["track_name"] = $result["track_name"];
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
        echoRespnse(404, $response);
    }
});
```

This is the **getTracksByName()** function for returning a list a tracks after matching the album name,

```
public function getTracksByName($album_keyword) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
        "SELECT `album`.album_name, `track`.track_artist, `track`.track_name "
        . "FROM `category_album` ,`album` , `track` "
        . "where `album`.album_id=`track`.album_id AND`album`.`album_name` LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $album_keyword);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $res = array();
        $stmt->bind_result($album_name, $track_artist, $track_name);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $res["album_name"] = $album_name;
        $res["track_artist"] = $track_artist;
        $res["track_name"] = $track_name;
        $stmt->close();
        return $res;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Now after making the REST call its returns null values for each track items. Just to mention I've change the SQL query from

**... AND`album`.`album_name` LIKE ?**

to

**... AND`album`.`album_id` LIKE ?**

and its works but for some reason itsn't working with the following query

**... AND`album`.`album_name` LIKE ?**

I'm absolutely new to PHP and any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->bind_param("i", $album_keyword);` binds a parameter of type `INTEGER`. Change to `$stmt->bind_param("s", $album_keyword);` to bind a parameter of type `STRING`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

There is two potential issues in your prepared statement code.

First off, you are telling the statement that the parameter is a int:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $album_keyword);
```

The `i` indicates Integer. While you want a string (`s`).

Second issue is that when using `LIKE` in a prepared statement, you still need the `%` signs used in a standard `LIKE`.

For example:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", "%$album_keyword%");
```